# Python3 list slice: specific use in class method

Tags: python, list, slice

I've seen plenty of Python list slice questions here, I don't believe I'm duplicating anything despite it touching on many of those same questions. My question relates to shortening a list using slices, to create a new list and to update the original list.

My task would be to define a `Class` method which accepts two arguments `(word_list, num)` and manipulate `word_list` using slicing. I keep slicing until `word_list` is empty, storing each slice in a new list. It's not important which end I slice from in terms of the contents of the slice but simply that I can keep slicing and maintain an accurate record of events.

Take the following:

```
word_list = ["once", "upon", "a", "time", "there", "lived", "an", "old", "man"]

sub_list1 = word_list[:2] # ["once", "upon"]
word_list = word_list[2:] # ["a", "time", "there", "lived", "an", "old", "man"]
```

compare this with

```
word_list = ["once", "upon", "a", "time", "there", "lived", "an", "old", "man"]

sub_list2 = word_list[-2:] # ["old", "man"]
word_list = word_list[:-2] # ["once", "upon", "a", "time", "there", "lived"]
```

In the first example above the list elements get "shunted down" as the slices are taken, as opposed to the second wherein the list simply gets shorter and nothing "moves". Am I inventing a problem or are there any actual implications in slicing `word_list` differently?

Comment: The only difference I can think of is that if there are an odd number of words(since you're using `:2` and `2:`) the part of the list that gets the last "odd item" will either contain the first element, or the last element, and where it is will depend on which implementation you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended slice syntax works by creating a `slice` object to pass to the appropriate `__getitem__` method. `foo[x:y:z]` becomes `foo.__getitem__(slice(x, y, z))`.

No assumptions are made about missing values; the value `None` is simply passed along to `slice`. So your expressions become

```
word_list[:2]   -> word_list.__getitem__(slice(None, 2, None))
word_list[2:]   -> word_list.__getitem__(slice(2, None, None))
word_list[:-2]   -> word_list.__getitem__(slice(None, -2, None))
word_list[-2:]   -> word_list.__getitem__(slice(-2, None, None))
```

It is up to the implementation of `__getitem__` to decide how to treat each `None` value. Typically, context is taken into account. If the step is positive, a missing start is treated as 0; if it's negative, as `-1`. A missing step usually defaults to 1, regardless of the start and stop positions; that's why something like `foo[10:0]` is empty rather than assuming you want to use a step of -1.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if I understand your issue, but I can't see any  actual implications between your first and second example, it is just your interpretation

you can have a look over the performance whitch is the same:

```
import numpy as np
import struct
import sys

from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder
b = BenchmarkBuilder()

@b.add_function()
def positive_slicing(my_list):
    sub_list = my_list[:2]
    my_list = my_list[2:]

@b.add_function()
def negative_slicing(my_list):
    sub_list = my_list[-2:]
    my_list = my_list[:-2]

@b.add_arguments('slicing list')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(2, 7):
        size = 10**exp
        yield size, ['some random example'] * size

r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you - very informative. It wasn't an 'issue' as such. I'm learning, and wanted to know if there were any accepted best practice or potential pitfalls of one method vs. the other. Thank you for helping.